# Is there a way to catalog data in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, catalog

Is there a way in snowflake to describe/catalog schema so it is easier to search? For example, column name is "s_id", which really represents "system identifier". Is there a way to specify that s_id is "system identifier" and user can search "system identifier", which would return s_id as column name.

Answer (score 0):

Just about every object in Snowflake allows for a comment to be added.  You could leverage the comment field to be more descriptive of the columns intent, which can then be searched in `information_schema.columns`.  I've seen many Snowflake customers use the comments as a full-blown data dictionary.  My only suggestion is to not use any apostrophe's in your comments, as they screw up your `get_ddl()` results.

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments along with table and field can or may serve the purpose but if you are in a complex enterprise environment and a lot of groups are part of it, it will be hard to follow this approach for long. Either you must have single ownership for data models tool which promotes such changes to the snowflake. Managing such information via comment is error-prone and that's why snowflake has partners which help on the different development requirement.

If you go to their partner website ([link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem-all.html)), you will find a lot of companies that have good integration with SF and one of them is Alation ([link](https://www.alation.com/)). You can try it for free for 30 days and see if that serves your purpose of data cataloging or not.